Kafka Streams TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics
A. I'm using Kafka Streams, and have built a topology that does an outerJoin on two input topics.
When starting the topology, I'm getting org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [foobar-topic]
#error {
 :cause "Not authorized to access topics: [foobar-topic]"
 :via
 [{:type org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException
   :message "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [foobar-topic]"
   :at [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread runLoop "StreamThread.java" 657]}
  {:type org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException
   :message "Not authorized to access topics: [foobar-topic]"}]
 :trace
 []}

B. But foobar-topic exists. And foobar-topic also has an ACL.
When I look at the Kafka Streams / Developer Guide / Streams Security, I have the Required ACL setting for secure Kafka clusters.
C. I think that I've supplied the needed configuration to the Consumer inside the Streams application.
16:19:58.970 [nREPL-session-5c4d3480-07a5-4139-a825-77914a5ce5f1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = false
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [hidden]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = foobar-topology-toplogy-8b42b110-61dc-4d54-8bb9-964bc44d413a-StreamThread-1-consumer
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = A-join-toplogy
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = false
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 45000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = /credentials/ssl/keystore
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = /credentials/ssl/truststore
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

D. This question is similar to Kafka stream: "TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics" for an internal state store.
But the changelog topic already exists in this case. We're just trying to access it.
=> And as a sanity check, I started a plain jane Kafka Consumer with the same keystore and truststore. And that started up fine.
What am I missing here?
